# Passenger Using Incorrect Ruby Version

Tags: apache, passenger

I Had a Vhost using Ruby 2.6.0, and updated the gemfile to use 2.6.6.

I don't know why it keeps looking at the 2.6.0 Ruby. Yes I have restarted Apache, and even put a fresh install of passenger in.

My vhost entry looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.railgun.test
    DocumentRoot /Users/romuloux/Sites/rail_gun/public
    PassengerStickySessions on
    PassengerRuby /Users/romuloux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby
    RailsEnv development
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/httpd/certs/api.railgun.test.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/etc/httpd/certs/api.railgun.test.key"
    <Directory /Users/romuloux/Sites/rail_gun/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Exception
`Could not find erubi-1.10.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Backtrace

```
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:365:in `activate_gem'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:529:in `running_bundler'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:382:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/Users/romuloux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/passenger-6.0.7/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Also, using `rails s` and not running through Passenger/Apache, things work as expected.

Any other places to check?